# Does Facebook recognize vanity URLs?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created a website using a vanity domain extension, http://thatme.me. I've added the necessary OpenGraph meta tags for the urls to display all pretty on Facebook. If a user posts a full URL, for example http://thatme.me/notbad, the OpenGraph data gets pulled and shows the image on the post. However, if a user only types a url like this thatme.me/notbad the URL is not recognized and the OpenGraph data doesn't show.

Is there something I need to do so that those URLs will be recognized or am I just out of luck?

Comment: Do you mean when they type the 'URL' without the protocol identifier? I don't think the URL detection covers URLs without the protocol identifier

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean

Comment: Ah, i don't think that works for any URL, no specifically 'vanity url' type URLs - only urls with a protocol identifier are auto-detected in my experience

Comment: When I type `thatme.me/notbad` into a FB status update, it auto-detects and shows me the OG metadata.  Typing `thatme.me` alone does not trigger auto-detect though.